# Stored procedure Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE NearUnits
    @lat float,
    @lng float
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT Uname, Latitude, Longitude,Info, 
  (
     6371 * acos(
       sin(@lat/57.295800) * 
       sin(Latitude/57.295800) + 
       cos(@lat/57.295800) * 
       cos(Latitude/57.295800) * 
       cos(@lng/57.295800 - Longitude / 57.295800)
     )
  ) AS distance 
  FROM [dbo].[MedicalUnit]
) mytable
WHERE distance <= 20;
END;
```

When I execute it:

```
NearUnits 31.0333449532716,31.3618322632
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure NearUnits, Line 6
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Although it was working normally before !!!

any solutions??

Comment: What is the schema of the table?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean with schema ?

Comment: Schema is the data type pif the column of the table and its keys possibly indicies - However you should know this before doing andy SQL I would reread your tutorial - if you don't understand this term there are likely to be other things that you won't understand in any replies from us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tray casting Latitude or Longitude:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE NearUnits
    @lat float,
    @lng float
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT Uname, Latitude, Longitude,Info, 
  (
     6371 * acos(
       sin(@lat/57.295800) * 
       sin(CAST(Latitude AS float)/57.295800) + 
       cos(@lat/57.295800) * 
       cos(CAST(Latitude AS float)/57.295800) * 
       cos(@lng/57.295800 - CAST(Longitude AS float) / 57.295800)
     )
  ) AS distance 
  FROM [dbo].[MedicalUnit]
) mytable
WHERE distance <= 20;
END;
```